# Is The Simple Subject Earth Or Dinosaurs?

Tags: grammar

What is the simple subject of the following sentence?

> The disappearance from the earth of those great creatures, the dinosaurs, still remain a mystery.

Is the simple subject "dinosaurs" or "earth"? Or perhaps is it "disappearance" or "mystery".

Comment: You've been asking a series of questions that, as a whole, seem to be copies of homework assignments. This site shouldn't be used for the purpose of homework. When asking these questions, don't just ask for answers—indicate what you think and *why*.

Comment: Please read the "[Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4785)" and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).To improve your question: **what do you think the answer could be** and what research have you done?

Answer (score 2):

disappearance

The disappearance remains a mystery.  You wouldn't say the dinosaurs remain a mystery, or the earth remains a mystery.

"earth" is object of the proposition "from", dinosaurs is part of a parenthetical that describes "those great creatures".

"mystery" is a subject complement for "remain" which is acting as a linking verb here.

Comment: So, is it disappearance?

Comment: yes, "disappearance" is the simple subject